# want to achieve cards functionality in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

[image]

HI ALL,

I want to achieve this functionality. when I click ADD on the item, the item is automatically added to the apex_collection. How to achieve this in oracle apex

I have tried classic report with cards template but got stuck in the middle

I have created the cards. Now want to add data to the apex_collection.... For that I have column links
Target : URL
URL : javascript:$s('P8_ACTION','#PRODUCT_CODE#');

Also created the hidden item P8_ACTION and added
dynamic action--> execute server side

`Begin IF not apex_collection.collection_exists('MY_COLLECTION') then apex_collection.create_collection('MY_COLLECTION');  end if; apex_collection.add_member( p_collection_name => 'MY_COLLECTION', p_c001 => :P8_ACTION );  END;  /`

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What version of apex are you on ? "Cards Region" was introduced in 20.2 It looks a lot like what you're describing (https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/a-simple-guide-to-the-new-cards-region-in-apex-202)

Comment: I am using Oracle APEX 22.2.4

Comment: I have created the cards. Now want to add data to the apex_collection....
For that I have column links
Target : URL 
URL : javascript:$s('P8_ACTION','#PRODUCT_CODE#');

Also created the hidden item P8_ACTION and added dynamic action--> execute server side

Begin
  IF not apex_collection.collection_exists('MY_COLLECTION') then
    apex_collection.create_collection('MY_COLLECTION');
    end if;

  apex_collection.add_member(
    p_collection_name => 'MY_COLLECTION',
    p_c001           => :P8_ACTION
  );
  
END;
/

Comment: Is P8_ACTION listed in 'page items to submit' attribute on the DA action? Do you then refresh your IG afterwards, or check session state to see if the record is in your collection?

Comment: Please don't post code updates in comments. Instead update your question (do not replace your original post)

Comment: Yes, I have P8_ACTION item has DA, Once the values are stored to the collection then we need to refresh the IG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on the EMP table. It's using a javascript custom event which means all javascript nicely grouped in the dynamic action.

###### Create Cards Report

- Generate a cards region through the wizard on the sample data `EMP` table. Just take the defaults. Note that this is NOT a classic report. Is is a region of type "Cards".
- Add a button to the card: In "Body" section of the card, add HTML Expression with source

```
<button data-id=&EMPNO. type="button" class="add-emp t-Button t-Button--success">Add</button>
```

Note the `data-id=&EMPNO.` attribute and `add-emp` class

[image]

Button was build using [button builder](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/button-builder)

Add a page item to the region to store the selected EMPNO (P158_EMPNO)

###### Dynamic Action

[image]

- True action 1 (Set value of P158_EMPNO on button click)

  - Action "Set Value"
  - Set Type "Javascript Expression"
  - this.triggeringElement.dataset['id']
  - Affected Elements. `P158_EMPNO`
- True Action 2 (Add row to collection)

  - Action "Execute Server-side Code"
  - Code

```
DECLARE
  l_collection VARCHAR2(100) := 'EMP';
BEGIN
  IF NOT APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_EXISTS (p_collection_name => l_collection) THEN
    APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION(p_collection_name => l_collection);
  END IF;
  APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBER (
    p_collection_name => l_collection,
    p_n001 => :P158_EMPNO);
END;
```

- Items to submit `P158_EMPNO`

Note that this is basic code. It does allow a record to add more than once, I'm not cleaning up the collection etc. But you should get the point.

Comment: I believe this can be achieved on the modal dialog page but I want it on the Nomal page

Comment: I don't understand your comment. My example is is not dependent on modal or non-modal pages. It works for any page. Do not use a classic report, use a region of type "Card Region" - it is way more powerful than a classic report with the cards template.

Comment: When I create a region with Card Type, There is no option to add the HTML code u have provided (previous comments)